# How does Normal reaction work to provide Centrifugal force in a banked road when some of force due to gravity is already there?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram

I came across the problem-

> A turn of radius 20m is banked for the vehicles going at a speed 36km/hr. If the coefficient of static friction between road and the is 0.4, what are the possible speeds of a vehicle so that it neither slips down or skids up?

While solving it, I come across resolving forces along the road as frictional force, sine of force due to gravity and also Sine of Normal Reaction force which just complicates the solution

What is the way to solve this question as the solution I have just says ignore normal reaction and then solve the question, and it works. How? I mean if Normal reaction is giving the force, why is it not in the Free Body Diagram?

[image]

Comment: See [Friction on roads](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60985)

Comment: Whoa that was so really different that what I asked

Comment: -1 The problem is almost identical to yours. It does not answer your particular question about normal reaction. It does show how to solve the problem. [Car on a frictionless banked curve](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90303) asks about the normal force. Normal reaction is needed to provide centripetal force, so it should be included in the Free Body Diagram. You have not provided the solution which you are asking about so we cannot explain why normal reaction is not in the FBD.

Comment: Gonna do that quickly

Comment: The normal reaction is labelled $R$ in the diagrams.

Comment: Eqn (i) resolves forces perpendicular to the road, so normal reaction $R$ appears in this eqn. Eqn (ii) resolves forces parallel to the road, so friction force $\mu R$ appears in this eqn and normal force $R$ does not. When the car is about to slip, the maximum friction force is $\mu R$.

Comment: Cosine of gravity force appears in eqn (i) because that is the component perpendicular to the road.

Comment: Oh man,that’s it the solution is so ambiguous to understand anything... really thanks for helping out a newbie man,even I won’t have been able to do that

Comment: I have been deleting commments(sorry for it) cause you had already given answers to them before

Answer (score 0):

Normal actions is assumed to be absent because we consider that the frictional force is just enough to ensure car moves in a circular path and a limiting case that contact of car is just broken with road is taken I.e N=0

Comment: The normal force (labeled R) is included in the given diagrams and calculations.